# Nginx : Remove the trailing slash before params(?) and forward it and not redirect

Tags: nginx

I have url like /v1/path1/path2/?param1=a&param2=b.
I want this to be converted into /v1/path1/path2?param1=a&param2=b and forward it to the server.

I wrote a rewrite in Nginx conf but that is returning is 301 status code with a redirect which my clients are not able to handle.

So, can we check if the URL has an extra slash, then remove it and forward to the server using Nginx

Comment: By "forward it to the server" do you mean with a `proxy_pass` statement?

Comment: @RichardSmith I mean, sent to the backend behind the nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding rewrite `^/(.*)/$ /$1;` to conf in location

```
server {
  listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com;

  location / {
    set $request_body_head '';
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8003;
  }
}
```